# Select Parent..Child records from 2 tables in one query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables called YL0PF (which is the Master or Parent record) and YL1PF (which is the detail or Child record).

They join like this

```
YL0AB=YL1AB, YL0AN=YL1AN, YL0AS=YL1AS
```

and we restrict records by the column DTEINP.

There can be 0 to many detail records for 1 master record. The Child records are basically arrears records showing what months payments have been missed by the month they were due

So I can of course do this:

```
SELECT  Y0.* ,
        Y1.*
FROM    alpsProduction..YL0PF Y0
        LEFT OUTER JOIN alpsProduction..YL1PF Y1 ON Y0.L0AB = y1.L1AB
                                                    AND Y0.L0AN = Y1.L1AN
                                                    AND Y0.L0AS = Y1.L1AS
WHERE   Y0.DTEINP = '01 Jun 2015'
ORDER BY Y0.L0AB + Y0.L0AN + Y0.L0AS ,
        Y1.L1AB + Y1.L1AN + Y1.L1AS ,
        CAST(Y1.DTEINP AS DATE) DESC
```

and this will put the child records next to the repeating Parent records.

But if possible I would like to extract the data as below:

> L0AS1, L0AN1, L0AS1, *
>
> > L1AS1, L1AN1, L1AS1, *
> >
> > L1AS1, L1AN1, L1AS1, *
>
> L0AS2, L0AN2, L0AS2, *
>
> > L1AS2, L1AN2, L1AS2, *
> >
> > L1AS2, L1AN2, L1AS2, *
> >
> > L1AS2, L1AN2, L1AS2, *

So how could I do that?

Comment: your output is a little vague. can you add some sample input and expected output. are you looking to get the child values as comma seperated in a single row??

Comment: @ughai: Thanks for your quick response. I'd like the child records to show as columns below the parent records if possible

Comment: Why do you call tables and columns like this? This is extremely unreadable.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: Hi Giorgi, in fact these data tables match the source table names in the iSeries - and on there as you know, the naming convention is pretty dire for the files...

Comment: can you try giving sample input data and sample output you are expectng,You can use SQL fiddle too give some data which will help all